# node-fetch & netlify function "Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null"

Tags: netlify, node-fetch, netlify-function

netlify site name: https://liontime-api-redirect.netlify.app/

[error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f95ny.png)
you can see this image when you open the site above too.

I built a proxy server with netlify function.
It worked well at local development environment.
But after deployment, this error occurred.
I think something went wrong with fetch-blob, but I'm not sure because it worked well at local.

Can anyone help with this?